# I can't hide my paragraph with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

Hi guys I am not able to hide my paragraph and I don't know why.

[Here is mi jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaivalz/0xhg57e4/)

and my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Ejemplo 1</title>

    </head>
    <body>
            <p id="paragraph">This is Sparta</p>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hide.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


    $('#paragraph').click(function)  {


    $('#paragraph').hide();

});
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery anywhere? Also your javascript code needs to go inside of <script> tags or it won't be executed.

Comment: $('#paragraph').click(function()  {... etc  Syntax error, basically...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0xhg57e4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is your answer on '*How to hide ID element on click with jQuery*' that should have probably been your  question title.

**Answer:**

```
$('#paragraph').click(function() {
    $('#paragraph').hide(500);
});
```

**Also in your fiddle you weren't loading jQuery!**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Here is your updated working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/0xhg57e4/3/

Comment: @Jaime. The names Bond, James Bond.